# How to append last values in a column to all NAs in R?

Tags: r

## Data Frame

```
my.df <- data.frame(Vehid = rep(c(2,3), each=25), frameid = rep(c(1:25), 2), roll.corr = rep(c(rep(0.3,3), 0.4,0.6, rep(0.7,12), 0.6,0.5,0.5,0.4, rep(NA,4)),2),
                    framestart = rep(c(1:21, rep(NA, 4)),2), frameend = rep(c(5:25, rep(NA,4)),2))
```

## Required

For a `vehid` I want to get the last value before `NA`, e.g. 0.4 in this case, and replace all `NA`s with that value.

## What I tried

If the data frame has only 1 `vehid`, following works:

```
my.df$roll.corr[is.na(my.df$roll.corr)] <- my.df$roll.corr[head(which(match(my.df$roll.corr, NA)==1),1)-1]
```

There must be a simple way to do this but I could only do above. Now, for multiple `vehid`s I tried to use `ddply` after defining the above as a function as follows but it didn't work:

```
my.func <- function(b){
  b[is.na(b)] = b[head(which(match(b,NA)==1),1)-1]
}

ddply(my.df, .(Vehid), my.func(roll.corr))
```

It gives the error that `object roll.corr not found`.

## Desired Output

```
my.df <- data.frame(Vehid = rep(c(2,3), each=25), frameid = rep(c(1:25), 2), roll.corr = rep(c(rep(0.3,3), 0.4,0.6, rep(0.7,12), 0.6,0.5,0.5,0.4, rep(0.4,4)),2),
                    framestart = rep(c(1:21, rep(NA, 4)),2), frameend = rep(c(5:25, rep(NA,4)),2))
```

Please suggest a simple solution.

Comment: Something like `na.locf` from the "zoo" package?

Comment: I believe @AnandaMahto's proposal to guide you into the right direction. locf stands for Last Observation Carry Forward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would probably be to use `na.locf` from the "zoo" package.

You should be able to do something like:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(my.df$roll.corr)
#  [1] 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7
# [17] 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.5 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.7 0.7
# [33] 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.5 0.4 0.4 0.4
# [49] 0.4 0.4
```

Comment: @Vlo, I think they only wanted the `roll.corr` column changed. Also, `na.locf` works on a `data.frame` too, so `na.locf(my.df)` would be sufficient :-)

Comment: @umairdurrani, does the answer not work for you in some way? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It works for the sample data frame in the question but it doesn't work for my original data frame which has about 1300 unique `vehid`s. The error I get is `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Roll.Corr", value = c(0.812056303412953,  : 
  replacement has 429509 rows, data has 429828`

Comment: I'm not sure that's to do with the number of unique "vehid"s. I'd suggest trying to come up with a MRE that demonstrates the error you mention. Chances are that in the process, you'll also solve the problem :-)